# How to prevent flexbox from shrinking vertically or height wise

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs side by side in my HTML page:

[image]

and I made the outer container flex so that two divs can be placed side by side as shown above.

Now i understand that if a container is made to flex, it will shrink or grow depending on the width or height of the browser, however is it possible to **only let it flex width wise or horizontally**?

[image]

As shown above, if i adjust the width of the browser it flexes accordingly.

However what i want to do now is to **not let it flex height wise** or **vertically**, because the content starts getting **messy**:

[image]

Is it possible to **disable flex property based on height** and allow for **scrollbars** to occur instead?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#first {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#second {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.output_entity {
    height: 4%;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 28% 45% 27%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}

.output_entity label {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container">
    <div id = "first">
      <div class = "output_entity">
        <label id = "">Name</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "name" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class = "output_entity">
        <label id = "">Amount</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "amount" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "second">
      <div class= "sample_text">
        <p>This is a sample text</p>
      </div>
      <div class= "sample_text">
        <p>This is another sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of Flexbox, this is rather a problem of your rules.

You specify the height of `.output_entity` to be 4% of its parent.

However, when its content doesn't fit into this small of an area, it overflows, which is (by default) visible.
When overflowing, it seems like it overlaps with other elements (which it visually does), which is what you see.

To fix this, just remove the line `height: 4%` from `.output_entity`.

If you really wanted to change how the elements are layed out along the secondary direction (by that I mean the direction perpendicular to the `flex-direction`), you could use the property `align-items` with one of its options.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#first {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#second {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.output_entity {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 28% 45% 27%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}

.output_entity label {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container">
    <div id = "first">
      <div class = "output_entity">
        <label id = "">Name</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "name" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class = "output_entity">
        <label id = "">Amount</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "amount" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "second">
      <div class= "sample_text">
        <p>This is a sample text</p>
      </div>
      <div class= "sample_text">
        <p>This is another sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. Therefore if I would want a larger text box, I should assign the height and width property to the textbox instead of the outer .output_entity container?

Comment: Yes, you should (in _my_ opinion) define dimensions on the elements themselves, and the layout on the parent. I find that easier to debug, and less error-prone.

Comment: thank you. Since I removed the % height of .output_entity, my guess is to use the vh unit on the textbox height if i want to make it taller and vw unit to make it longer? Since i want to avoid fixed unit like px as different laptop have different screen dimension.

Comment: You can use relative units like `rem`, which will scale as long as you set the `<meta name="viewport">` tag correctly. `rem` uses the font-size of your root-element, which is `<html>`. You can try it out a bit, and use the browser's DevTools for testing with simulated device dimensions!